# Setting the value of a nested array element based on a dynamic list of keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, javascript-objects

I have a dynamically-generated object like so (I'm just noting the 'children' array keys here for display purposes, assume its an otherwise syntactically sound array):

```
foo: {
    children: [
        0: {
            children: [
               3: { 
                   children: [
                       6: {
                           //...etc
```

I then have a list of keys being generated:

```
var keys = [0,3,6];
```

And I need to set the value of the element of the array described by the list of keys, as such:

```
foo.children[0].children[3].children[6] = "bar";
```

Any ideas?  I've tried a few different recursive techniques, but I'm missing something somewhere.

Comment: Can you create a function to accept keys array as an argument, loop through each key and attach it to your dot notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could do this recursively, I think it is more efficient to do it in a loop like this:

```
function setNestedChild( obj, path, value ){
    var child = obj;
    path.forEach(function( i, idx ){
        if( idx == path.length - 1 ){
            child.children[ i ] = value;
        }
        else {
            child = child.children[ i ];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I actually ended up solving my own question after a few hours, but this was identical to what I did (just with a for loop instead of a forEach), so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about a method along the lines of

```
def function getElement (keys) {
  var el = this.foo

  for (i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    el = el.children[keys[i]]
  }

  return el
}
```

- This function is just to retrieve the desired element doesn't actually set the value.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
function setVal(obj, keys, val){
    var temp = obj;
    while(keys.length){
        var i = keys.pop();
        if(!keys.length) return temp.children[i] = val;
        temp = temp.children[i];
    }   
}
```